# How To Get Values From UISegmentcontroller

Tags: iphone, uisegmentedcontrol

I Created Segment Control through Interface Builder.
Created a IBAction and Linked to Value Changed Option of segment Controller.

```
- (IBAction)GenderBttonAction:(id)sender {
    printf("\n Segemt Controll");
   }
```

When i click on segment controller this method is calling , but how would i get the seleced index value of segment controller.
Please help me dears.

Answer (score 7):

```
((UISegmentedControl *)sender).selectedSegmentIndex;
```

:-)

Comment: Hey Alfons, Many Many Thanks ... U R My Hero Really

Comment: iappdevs: Perhaps a good read of the UISegmentedControl documentation would be helpful...

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code in a view controller.m to say launch a modal controller and it seems to work good for me.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    NSArray *segmentContent = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               NSLocalizedString(@"view 1", @""),
                               NSLocalizedString(@"view 2", @""),
                               NSLocalizedString(@"Close", @""),
                               nil];
     //or images insted of text
     //NSArray *segmentContent = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
        //                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"],
        //                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"spic.png"],
        //                          [UIImage imageNamed:@"close.png"],
        //                          nil]];


    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:segmentContent];
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = UISegmentedControlNoSegment;
    segmentedControl.momentary = YES; // option
    segmentedControl.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
    segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 30);
    [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    UIBarButtonItem *segments = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];
    [segmentedControl release];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segments;
    self.navigationItem.title = @"My title";
    [segments release];
```

Then add the actions on selection, last one is a close statement if you launched a modal controller.

```
- (IBAction)segmentAction:(id)sender
{
    UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *)sender;
    switch ([sender selectedSegmentIndex])
    {
        case 0: 
        {   



// Do stuff like launch a modal controller. But don't forget to add this all into your modal controller views to get back out :)
InfoViewController *infoViewController = [[InfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
            UINavigationController *aInfoViewController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:infoViewController];
            [self presentModalViewController:aInfoViewController animated:YES];


        break;
    }
    case 1: 
    {



// do stuff



break;
    }
    case 2: 
    {
        [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];         
        break;
    }
}
NSLog(@"Segment clicked: %d", segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex);
}
```

Use the method below if needed to close the modal via this way.

```
- (IBAction)dismissAction:(id)sender
{
    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and don't forget to declare the action/method in the same respective h file.

```
- (IBAction)dismissAction:(id)sender;
```

Hope this helps.

Sincerely, Kirk